# Wicket : Redirect a form before its components rendered

Tags: wicket-1.6

Is there any way we can submit the form before its components are rendered on page??

If I have link named "**Check Enquiry**", on click of which I am navigating to a wicket page "**Check Enquiry Page**" .On Check Enquiry page, I have buttons "**Search**" and "**Cancel**".I can give input details and click "**Search**" **button** to navigate to "**Search results Page**".

Is there any way so that on click of link "**Check Enquiry**" , directly I can navigate to "**Search Results Page**"

I want the solution only in form submission instead of setResponsePage("SearchresultsPage").

Comment: The description is not very clear.

Comment: Why would you do an auto-form submission in between? I don't understand the use case. Why not simply make it so the onclick of "Check Enquiry" leads to "Search Results Page" without the inbetween form? Please explain.